# Matching specific pattern in Angular Router

Tags: angular, express, routes

Rather than structure my component's url like this `mysite.com/map/cell/3/7`  I want to structure it like this `mysite.com/map/3,7` and be able to retrieve the first value as "row" and the second as "cell".

How would I achieve this?

PS: If possible I also need to know how to get Express to understand this so my Universal app will render it correctly.

Comment: Could someone please enlighten me as to why this question should be closed? Surely it is a valid question regarding routing strategies?

Answer (score 0):

If I need to do that I'd probably follow next pattern:

**Define the route:**

```
{ path: 'map/cell/:rowColumn', component: MyComponent }
```

**component.ts**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
            params => {
                const paramsArray = params.rowColumn.split(',');
                const row = paramsArray[0];
                const cell = paramsArray[1];
            }
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. In the route's definition, you should define a `matcher` instead of a `url`.

```
export const MyRouteMatcher = segments: UrlSegment[], segmentGroup: UrlSegmentGroup, route: Route): UrlMatchResult {
  // 1: Check it matches your pattern, if not then return null
  const parameterValues: { [key: string]: UrlSegment } = {};
  parameterValues['row'] = new UrlSegment(valueForRow, null);
  parameterValues['cell'] = new UrlSegment(valueForCell, null);

  return {
    consumed: segments,
    posParams: parameterValues
  }
}
```